# partition not recognized drive wont mount

Tags: mount, encryption, partitioning, antivirus

I have a wicked virus on my windows drive that can't be located for some reason. Virus scans always lock up the PC which always ends in a crash. I installed Ubuntu on my external drive to operate the PC. The internal drive does not show up to allow me to mount it. When I open it with gparted the partition /dev/sda2 is being shown as unknown. The drive is encrypted, I don't know it that is the reason for it not being identified or because the virus messed up my file system so bad its not recognized. I need to drive to show up so I can scan it from Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know much about Windows disk encryption, but [this page](http://superuser.com/questions/376533/how-to-access-a-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-in-linux) suggests Linux can access Windows encrypted disks with an add-on tool. If you need more help, please edit your post to include the output of `sudo parted -l` and `sudo blkid`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe virus has corrupted your partition table. If you have Windows as second OS you can use Unformat for data recognition and recovery. After that you can delete partition and create the new one. If you want to monitor your partition from Ubuntu you could try this:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step